# Shortcode: display list of created shortcode in popup

Tags: shortcode

I want to create a popup shortcode in admin panel. 
I already create the shortcode button and a popup on button click.

I want to display in the popup (not in the shortcode button), all my custom shortcodes that I have created in a dropdown list.

I really don't know how to get my shortcodes name with a loop like this for example:

```
<tbody>
<select id="shortcode-generator-select">
<option value="raw"></option>
<?php foreach( $shortcode as $shortcode ) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo $shortcode['name']; ?>"><?php echo $shortcode['title']; ?>    </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</tbody>
```

I just want to understand what is the way to create a popup shortcode generator.

Answer (score 2):

You get all shortcodes, there are registered in WordPress with the default function in the global `$shortcode_tags`. You can loop about this shortcodes and filter via tag or functiion.

```
foreach( $shortcode_tags as $tag => $function ) {

}
```

If the `$function` is a array, then can also read the parameters. See the source below. I think the source is easier to understand as my english ;)

```
    /**
     * Get all shortocdes and his data
     * 
     * @return String
     */
    function get_shortcodes() {
            global $shortcode_tags;

            $style   = '';
            $output  = '<h4>Total Shortcodes: ' . count( $shortcode_tags ) . '</h4>';
            $output .= '<ol>';
            foreach( $shortcode_tags as $tag => $function ) {

                    $style = ( ' class="alternate"' == $style ) ? '' : ' class="alternate"';

                    if ( is_string( $function ) ) {

                            $function = '<code>' . $function . '</code>';

                    } else if ( is_array( $function ) ) {

                            $object = '';
                            $parameters = '';
                            if ( is_string( $function[0] ) ) {

                                    $object = $function[0];

                            } else if ( is_object( $function[0] ) ) {

                                    $object = get_class( $function[0] );
                                    foreach ( $function[0] as $parameter => $value ) {

                                            // if the array is empty
                                            if ( empty( $value ) )
                                                    $value = __( 'The Array is empty' );

                                            $parameters .=  '<li><code>' . $parameter . '</code> => <code>' . $value . '</code></li>';
                                    }

                            }

                            if ( ! empty( $parameters ) )
                                    $parameters = '<br><strong>Parameters of class:</strong><ul>' . $parameters . '</ul>';
                            $function = '<code>' . $object . '::' . $function[1] . '</code>' . $parameters;
                    }
                    else {
                            $function = 'empty';
                    }


                    $output .= "<li$style><strong>Shortcode: </strong><code>$tag</code> <strong>Function: </strong>$function</li>";
            }

            $output .= '</ol>';

            echo $output;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However I have two errors with your code. I can't write `public` before the function. It gives an error. If I remove public, I've got an error on the foreach loop: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`...

Comment: The code is a method of my debug plugin, the public string is always usable in a class. The follow problem is that, the global is empty. Init the function via a hook, like `init` or `plugins_loaded` - `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'get_shortcodes' );` You can see the function in action with this [plugin class](https://github.com/bueltge/Debug-Objects/blob/master/inc/class-shortcodes.php).

Answer (score 0):

shortcodes get added to the global $shortcode_tags array as they are registred/added. Therefore you can access them thusly:

```
global $shortcode_tags;
foreach( $shortcode_tags as $shortcode ) {
 //do something
}
```

The array uses shortcode tags as the keys and the function called as the value, you'll probably have to figure out some way to further process them to get any meaningful information, and in fact since you state that you only want to list your own custom shortcodes, then this is probably the wrong approach anyhow.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I didn't success with your code... ANd is there a way to do it only with my custom shortcode. They are all in a same php file.

Comment: of course the code I posted didn't work. it isn't supposed to do anything. What did YOU do with it that isn't working?

Comment: the same thing that I have in my question...

Comment: there is no array key called 'name' or 'title' in the $shortcode_tags array so of course it won't output anything. try something like this: `foreach( $shortcode_tags as $key => $value ) { echo $key . ' '  . $value; }`

Comment: Ok. It works. Maybe to only echo my custom shortcode, I can filter $key and $value with my prefix theme name?

Comment: that would probably do the trick - something like strpos should do it.

Comment: Ok it works. And if I want to get the params fields to set up the shortcode? Is it the same way?